# Make Offer vs Extend Offer

Tags: word-choice

Talking about job offers what is the best/right/usual way to say it:

1. To make an offer
2. To extend an offer

Is there any difference? Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes there isn't much of a _best/right/usual_ between two options; sometimes, two wordings are both simply _acceptable/correct/common_, and there's not much else that can be said about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be at the discretion of the user. Both sentences are valid, and would work in a given scenario.

it's really about how you would want to go about it and, in the end, doesn't make much of a difference at all.

All that being said, I personally would "make an offer", because i feel it sounds more natural.